# Proving efficiency of OLS over GLS

Tags: regression, self-study, linear-algebra, generalized-least-squares, inequality

I'm trying to *prove* the efficiency of OLS over GLS when the covariance matrix of the error $\varepsilon$ is mistakenly assumed to be $\sigma^2\Sigma$ instead of $\sigma^2 I$. After deriving the variances, what I have so far is: $Var(\beta^{ols}) = \sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}$ and 
$Var(\beta^{gls}) = \sigma^2(X'\Sigma^{-1} X)^{-1}$.

Want to show $Var(\beta^{gls}) - Var(\beta^{ols})$ is psd.
$$\implies \sigma^2(X'\Sigma^{-1} X)^{-1} - \sigma^2(X'X)^{-1} \geq 0\\
\implies (X'\Sigma^{-1} X)^{-1} - (X'X)^{-1} \geq 0 \\
\iff X'X - X'\Sigma^{-1} X \geq 0
$$
But this is where I don't know how to proceed. First I tried $X'(I-\Sigma^{-1})X \geq 0$ but got stuck. Any hints on how to continue?

**Update**:
After one of the comments, I want to double check the variance of $\beta^{gls}$:
$$Var(\beta^{gls}) = Var[(X'\Sigma^{-1}X)^{-1} X'\Sigma^{-1}\varepsilon]\\
=(X'\Sigma^{-1}X)^{-1} X'\Sigma^{-1} Var(\varepsilon) \Sigma^{-1} X(X'\Sigma^{-1}X)^{-1}
$$
Here's is where I think I made the mistake, I replaced the variance of $\varepsilon$ as the one that we think is "right" (i.e. $\sigma^{2}\Sigma) $. Should I replace it with the real one (i.e. $\sigma^2I$)?

Comment: It seems to me the Gauss-Markov theorem implies this as part of its more general conclusion about the BLUE property of OLS, or am I missing something?

Comment: @jbowman I Agree with you, I saw the proof of Gauss-Markov on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem#Proof), I'm just having a hard time figuring out what would the D matrix used in the proof specifically for GLS.

Comment: Perhaps you could be able to use the properties of $\Sigma$? After all, it is not just any matrix, it must have some specific features.

Comment: When the variance matrix of $\varepsilon$ is $\sigma^2 I$, then $Var(\beta^{gls}) \neq \sigma^2(X'\Sigma^{-1} X)^{-1}$.

Comment: @RichardHardy Yes, it must be positive semidefinite and symmetric, which means it can be written $\Sigma = \Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}} \Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}}$, but I still cannot get it.

Comment: Not only that, there is some scaling involved, I suppose, you should be able to tell something about the sizes of the coefficients in $\Sigma$ once you have taken out the common denominator $\sigma$.

Comment: Your update goes in the right direction. What about $cov(\beta^{ols},\beta^{gls})$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:
$$Var(\beta^{gls}) = Var[(X'\Sigma^{-1}X)^{-1} X'\Sigma^{-1}\varepsilon]\\
=(X'\Sigma^{-1}X)^{-1} X'\Sigma^{-1} Var(\varepsilon) \Sigma^{-1} X(X'\Sigma^{-1}X)^{-1}\\
= \sigma^2 (X'\Sigma^{-1}X)^{-1} X'\Sigma^{-1} \Sigma^{-1} X(X'\Sigma^{-1}X)^{-1}\\
$$

Want to show $Var(\beta^{gls}) - Var(\beta^{ols})$ is psd.
$$\implies \sigma^2 (X'\Sigma^{-1}X)^{-1} X'\Sigma^{-1} \Sigma^{-1} X(X'\Sigma^{-1}X)^{-1} - \sigma^2(X'X)^{-1} \geq 0\\
\iff X'X - X'\Sigma^{-1}X( X'\Sigma^{-1} \Sigma^{-1} X)^{-1}X'\Sigma^{-1}X \geq 0\\
\implies X'(I-\Sigma^{-1}X( X'\Sigma^{-1} \Sigma^{-1} X)^{-1}X'\Sigma^{-1})X \geq 0\\
\implies X'MX\geq0
$$
Where $M$ is the residual maker matrix, and since $M$ is psd, the statement holds.

Answer (score 0):

It is known that $V(\beta^{gls}-\beta^{ols}|X)$ is positive semidefinite. Here it turns out that $$V(\beta^{gls}-\beta^{ols}|X)=V(\beta^{gls}|X)-V(\beta^{ols}|X),$$ hence the conclusion that $\beta^{ols}$ is relatively more efficient than $\beta^{gls}$ if $V(\varepsilon|X)=\sigma^2I_N$.

Comment: How do we know that $V(\beta^{gls} - \beta{ols})|X)$ is psd?

Comment: Any variance matrix is positive semidefinite. This follows from its definition: $V[Z]=E[(Z−E[Z])(Z−E[Z])^T]$. Take $Z = \beta^{gls}-\beta^{ols}|X $

Comment: I agree with the variance statement, but then what would stop me from saying that $V(\beta^{OLS} - \beta^{GLS})$ is positive semidefinite too and apply the same argument? Anyhow, I think I got the proof and it was because of your initial  comment, so I really appreciate your help. I'll post it as soon as I have time.

Comment: Yes, indeed, in general $$V(\beta^{gls}-\beta^{ols}|X)=V(\beta^{ols}-\beta^{gls}|X)=V(\beta^{ols})-2cov(\beta^{gls},\beta^{ols}|X)+V(\beta^{ols}|X).$$In this particular case, however, this last expression boilds down to the above equality.